# MySQL query works fine on local server but gives error in live

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have just done my site live . Below is the simple query; it works fine on my localhost but not on the live server.

```
 select * from friends where action='chating'
```

It gives error "you have to use right syntax near where".

Please help me: why this happening, and how do I solve it?

Comment: We need to see more of your code.

Comment: Need more info.  What do you SQL tables look like? What's inside the action column? Chatting is misspelled as well.

Comment: @OneSneakyMofo You've obviously never heard of chating. (jk)

Comment: Maybe that's supposed to be 'cheating' or 'charting' or 'chasing'?  It doesn't matter; misspelling of a string might generate the wrong data, but not a syntax error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess your mysql version is different on local and live. Please check it.

I am sure it's `Mysql5.5` on live in which `ACTION` is new [**Reserved Keyword**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html). SO while if you using it as column name then you need to use **bacticks(`)** around it while using in query.

Try below :

```
 select * from friends where `action`='chating'
```

Comment: `'` is not a backtick. (Edit: thanks for editing the answer to the correct version. :) )

Comment: @ Amber Yes.You are right. I have noted that just after posted.and corrected before you commented. Thanks ....

Comment: Sniped!  Nice job, KingFisher!

Comment: New reserved keywords... talk about a gotcha. This also makes phpmyadmin's practice of putting backticks around everything suddenly seem less paranoid. Thanks for the timely answer!